# Using webhook with Docusign - will I be able to get custom fields?

Tags: docusignapi

I created an envelope with one signer, 1 template, 3 different docs. I added a custom field to the envelope. I send off the envelope and get the response back on the url I specified. I look at the response and I don't see the custom envelope field in there. Should it be sent along with the response? Here is what I sent:

```
 {
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "file id",
        "value": "1823456"
      }
    ]
  },
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "http://requestb.in/16avl8c1",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      }
    ],
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false"
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Gilbert",
                "email": "KathyGilbert11@xxx.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Here is document one of the test.docx",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Gilbert",
                "email": "KathyGilbert11@xxx.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "2",
        "name": "Here is document two of the test",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "3",
      "serverTemplates": 
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Gilbert",
                "email": "KathyGilbert11@xxx.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "3",
        "name": "Here is document three of the test",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the following document at 3:20 PM"
}
```

Comment: What I've seen is that document custom fields come over, but not the envelope custom fields.

Comment: Kathy, Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it did. I didn't realize that with a composite template that the custom fields would need to be a part of the inline template. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect webhook response will contain the Envelope Custom Fields if they were added to the envelope successfully.

For CompositeTemplates the CustomFields specified at the root level are ignored. You should specify  the Custom Fields within the inline template.

Troubleshooting Tip:You can do an additional Check to see if the Custom Fields are created by using [listCustomFields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/list/) api.

Here is an example.

```
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "customFields": {
                   "textCustomFields": [
                   {
                    "name": "file id",
                    "value": "1823456"
                   }
                  ]
                },
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Kathy Gilbert",
                            "email": "KathyGilbert11@xxx.com",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "roleName": "##Buyer1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```