# Error Sending Composite Template to Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to use the docusign-node-client to send an envelope using the createEnvelope class. This class sends a REST API request to the /envelopes endpoint. The envelope I am trying to send contains a Composite Template.

Here is the body I am attempting to send to docusign

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Sent from Node SDK",
  "emailBlurb": "Email body here",
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
        "required": false,
        "show": false,
        "value": "dealIdHere"
      }
    ]
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentBase64": "base64StringHere",
              "documentId": "1",
              "fileExtension": ".pdf",
              "name": "filename.pdf"
            }
          ],
          "envelope": {
            "emailBlurb": "Email body here",
            "emailSubject": "Sent from Node SDK",
            "customFields": {
              "textCustomFields": [
                {
                  "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                  "required": false,
                  "show": false,
                  "value": "dealIdHere"
                }
              ]
            },
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                  "email": "myEmail@domain.com",
                  "name": "My Name",
                  "recipientId": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

When I send this body I get the following error: **"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value specified for \'templateId\' in composite template sequence: 1"**

If I remove the serverTemplates array, I get this error: **"The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line."**

If I include a valid templateId in the serverTemplate object it creates an envelope successfully.

The as is application I am converting to Node JS used the Docusign SOAP API and is able to send composite templates with 1 to many documents. Each of these documents can be associated to their own document template or no docusign template.

Does docusign not accept composite templates without some sort of reference to a template id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying the `inlineTemplate.envelope` property incorrectly. You can define the recipients and custom fields directly within the inlineTemplate. You do not have to specify the emailSubject/emailBlurb within the inlineTemplate.

Also note that the custom fields specified at the root level will be ignored when using composite templates. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153369/1219543)

The following json should work for you.

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Sent from Node SDK",
    "emailBlurb": "Email body here",
    "status": "sent"
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "documents": [
                        {
                            "documentBase64": "base64StringHere",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "fileExtension": ".pdf",
                            "name": "filename.pdf"
                        }
                    ],

                    "customFields": {
                        "textCustomFields": [
                            {
                                "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                                "required": false,
                                "show": false,
                                "value": "dealIdHere"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "myEmail@domain.com",
                                "name": "My Name",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks not only for solving my problem but also providing me extra helpful information that will help to avoid more headaches in the future. I would give you a +1 but I do not have the reputation for it yet. I did however mark your answer as correct.